# Poor PySpark performance on Stand-alone cluster + Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a Spark slave inside a Docker container on AWS c4.8xlarge machines (one or more) and struggling to get the expected performance when compared to just using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) on my laptop (with quad-core Intel i7-6820HQ). *(see edit below, there is a huge overhead on same hardware as well)*

I'm looking for solutions to horizontally scale analytics model training with a "Multiprocessor" which can work in a single thread, multi-process or in a distributed Spark scenario:

```
class Multiprocessor:
    # ...

    def map(self, func, args):
        if has_pyspark:
            n_partitions = min(len(args), 1000)
            return _spark_context.parallelize(args, n_partitions).map(func).collect()
        elif self.max_n_parallel > 1:
            with multiprocessing.Pool(self.max_n_parallel) as pool:
                return list(pool.map(func, args))
        else:
            return list(map(func, args))
```

As you can see Spark's role is to distribute calculations and simply retrieve results, `parallelize().map()` is the only API used. `args` is just a list of integer id tuples, nothing too heavy.

I'm using Docker 1.12.1 (`--net host`), Spark 2.0.0 (stand-alone cluster), Hadoop 2.7, Python 3.5 and openjdk-7. Results for the same training dataset, every run is CPU-bound:

- 5.4 minutes with local multiprocessing (4 processes)
- 5.9 minutes with four c4.8xlarge slaves (10 cores in use / each)
- 6.9 minutes with local Spark (master `local[4]`)
- 7.7 minutes with three c4.8xlarge slaves (10 cores in use / each)
- 25 minutes with a single c4.8xlarge slave (10 cores) (!)
- 27 minutes with local VM Spark slave (4 cores) (!)

All 36 virtual CPUs seem to be in use, load averages are 250 - 350. There were about 360 `args` values to be mapped, their processing took 15 - 45 seconds (25th and 75th percentiles). CG times were insignificant. Even tried returning "empty" results to avoid network overhead but it did not affect the total time.  Ping to AWS via VPN is 50 - 60 ms.

[image: htop]

Any tips on which other metrics I should look into, feel I'm wasting lots CPU cycles somewhere. I'd really like to build architecture around Spark but based on these PoCs at least machines on AWS are way too expensive. Gotta do tests with other local hardware I've access to.

**EDIT 1**: Tested on a Linux VM on laptop, took 27 minutes when using the stand-alone cluster which is 20 minutes more than with `local[4]`.

**EDIT 2**: There seems to be 7 pyspark daemons for each slave "core", all of taking significant amount of CPU resources. Is this expected behavior? (picture from laptop's VM)

[image: pyspark daemons]

**EDIT 3**: Actually this happens even when starting the slave just a single core, I get 100% CPU utilization. According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/180724/240049) red color indicates kernel level threads, could Docker play a role here? Anyway, I don't remember seeing this issue when I was prototyping it with Python 2.7, I got very minimal performance overhead. Now updated to Java OpenJDK 8, it made no difference. Also got same results with Spark 1.5.0 and Hadoop 2.6.

[image: pyspark daemons 2]

**EDIT 4**: I could track down that by default `scipy.linalg.cho_factor` uses all available cores, that is why I'm seeing high CPU usage even with one core for the Spark slave. Must investigate further...

**Final edit**: The issue seems to have nothing to do with AWS or Spark, I've got poor performance on stand-alone Python within the Docker container. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39119433/3731823).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion (I'm the OP), it took me a while to dig down to what is really happening. I did lots of benchmarking and finally I realized that on Docker image I was using OpenBLAS which by default multithreads linalg functions. My code is running `cho_solve` hundreds of times on matrices of size ranging from `80 x 80` to `140 x 140`. There was simply tons of overhead from launching all these threads, which I don't need in the first place as I'm doing parallel computation via multiprocessing or Spark.

```
# N_CORES=4 python linalg_test.py
72.983 seconds

# OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 N_CORES=4 python linalg_test.py
9.075 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - for me the root cause was memory allocation.
Make sure you allocate enough memory to your spark instances.
In start-slave.sh - run --help to get the memory option (the default is 1GB per node regardless the actual memory in the machine).

You can view in the UI (port 8080 on the master) the allocated memory per node.

You also need to set the memory per executor when you submit your application, i.e. spark-submit (again the default is 1GB), like before - run with --help to get the memory option.

Hope this helps.